# CMake error while installing Hadoop 2.7.1 on Windows 7 SP1

Tags: java, windows, maven, hadoop, cmake

I am trying to install Hadoop 2.7.1 on Windows 7 SP1 (64-bit machine)

The build begins OK and then I get an error (shown below) which seems to indicate that CMake is improperly configured.  This leaves me somewhat stumped because (1) I have no experience compiling non-Java items and (2) the CMake installation process was just "run cmake-3.3.1-win32-x86.exe and let this process add itself to the path".  Consequently, there was little room to screw up the install process (perhaps?).

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................. SUCCESS [  1.779 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM .......................... SUCCESS [  1.824 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations .......................... SUCCESS [  3.323 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies ........................... SUCCESS [  0.156 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM ..................... SUCCESS [  2.544 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins ........................ SUCCESS [  3.466 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MiniKDC .............................. SUCCESS [  3.168 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth ................................. SUCCESS [  3.656 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples ........................ SUCCESS [  3.749 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common ............................... SUCCESS [02:13 min]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS .................................. SUCCESS [  6.263 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop KMS .................................. SUCCESS [ 12.704 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project ....................... SUCCESS [  0.035 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS ................................. FAILURE [ 25.703 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS BookKeeper Journal .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS-NFS ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Project ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-api .................................... SKIPPED

... a few more items are skipped and then it describes the error here:
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:24 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-10T10:29:33-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 96M/1027M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (make) on project hadoop-hdfs: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned:
1
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="C:\Tools\hadoop-2.7.1-src\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target/native" executable="cmake">... @ 8:125 in C
:\Tools\hadoop-2.7.1-src\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target\antrun\build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
```

The CMakeError.log file contains:

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
1
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : Configuration error MSB4146: Cannot evaluate the property expression "$([MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('$(VCTargetsPath)','$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\'))" found at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0@VCTargetsPath". Invalid static method invocation syntax: "[MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('$(VCTargetsPath)','$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\')". Method '[MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault' not found. Static method invocation should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`, `b`)). 


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
1
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : Configuration error MSB4146: Cannot evaluate the property expression "$([MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('$(VCTargetsPath)','$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\'))" found at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0@VCTargetsPath". Invalid static method invocation syntax: "[MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('$(VCTargetsPath)','$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\')". Method '[MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault' not found. Static method invocation should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`, `b`)).
```

The exact command I used was:  "mvn package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar" (which was called from a Windows SDK 7.1 command prompt)

I have been working on installing Hadoop on 64 bit windows for a few days now and here are 3 of the best resources I have found so far (I am trying to follow their lead as much as possible):

1. http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows  (with emphasis on
   the BUILDING.txt reference in section 2.4)
2. http://coderearth.org/building-hadoop-26-on-64-bit-windows-7.html
3. http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os

### I have installed:

JDK 1.8.0_25    -- Maven 3.3.3    -- Cygwin    -- ProtocolBuffer 2.5.0    -- CMake 3.3.1    -- Windows SDK    -- Windows.NET Framework 4.0

### These Environment Variables are set:

JAVA_HOME, M2_HOME (maven), Platform (value="x64")

### The following directories are on my path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin;  (according to another SO thread this needs to be higher than the cygwin\bin entry)
C:\Tools\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin;
C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;
C:\Tools\hadoop-2.7.1\bin;
C:\Tools\protoBuf;
C:\cygwin\bin;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Ulead Systems\MPEG;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;
C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Services\IPT\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\VIP Access Client\;
C:\Tools\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\
```

Answer (score 3):

The registry key 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0@VCTargetsPath`
found in the CMakeError.log above belongs to Visual Studio 2015. However the output of MSBuild looks like Visual Studio 2010. You probably had VS2015 installed and then uninstalled. The uninstaller of VS2015 has a bug, as it does not clean up the registry properly.

On a 64 bit machine, this key is in fact located at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions`. If there is a subkey named `14.0` delete it and the older MSBuild should work again.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  Sadly, I cannot confirm that this works as I no longer have either of these tools installed.  However, you correct that I did have multiple versions of Visual Studio installed on my machine at one point.

Comment: I bumped into this problem just now, and I don't have a 14.0 subkey sadly. Will try to see if I can fix it.

Comment: My solution applies to the error from the last line in @Ivan's CMakeError.log, which reads 'MSBUILD : Configuration error MSB4146: Cannot evaluate the property expression "$([MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('$(VCTargetsPath)','$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\'))" found at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0@VCTargetsPath". ....)
This happens after removal of an installation of VS2015. If you never had VS2015 installed, this does not apply to you. There might well be other reasons for the build to fail. Check your CMakeError.log